# WGS84 Coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

i'm having some trouble figuring out the following coordinates of some ground control points. Here are the contents of the .txt file:

```
Header>> Delimiter(,) FileFormat(Name,Lat(North),Lon(East),Ht(G),Codes) <<
100,5748337.054,714668.795,15.143,
101,5748343.635,714722.173,14.963,
102,5748268.013,714711.800,14.530,
103,5748267.503,714665.305,14.699,
```

For example the second row says `Lat(North)= 5748337.054` and `Lon(East)= 714668.795`. The coordinates supposed to be WGS84 coordinates but i'm not able to get the correct location (it should be Schenkenschanz in Germany).

Comment: https://awsm-tools.com/geo/utm-to-geographic try with 33N and your long (easting) lat(northing)

Comment: (31N) yours are UTM 31N projected coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the coordinates, you mentioned (e.g, the second row)

```
Lat(North)= 5748337.054 and Lon(East)= 714668.795
```

They are in the WGS84 system, UTM31  Schenkenschanz, 47533 Kleve, Deutschland

For more information about these coordinates, please use this [link](https://www.deine-berge.de/Rechner/Koordinaten/Dezimal/51.844508,6.116557).